# how to use isotope jquery plugin with various size of boxes

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-isotope

Hi I am very new to isotope plugin and very confused about everything.
For the layout which I shown in the image below..
What should I do to get the result? 
Because my box seems messy currently and cannot arrange well like first to 4th boxes in a row..
Please help me, thank you.

[image: the layout]

My code:
http://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/woBEjj

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  }
});
```

Comment: For help, you need to post your code

Comment: @Macsupport code attached